# Massive.js selecting specific nested fields from document

Tags: node.js, postgresql, jsonb, massivejs

I have the following document sturcture stored in a document table

```
 {
  firstname: '',
  surname: '',
  ...

  manager: {
    firstname: '',
    surname: ''
    ...
  }
 }
```

When selecting records with Massive.js i can limit the fields returned by providing an options object.

`await dbConn.table.findDoc(criteriaObj, { fields: ['firstname', 'surname'] })`;

This works great for root fields, but for nested objects; consider the `manager` field above, Massive returns that field as a JSON string rather than a parsed object.

`await dbConn.table.findDoc(criteriaObj, { fields: ['firstname', 'manager'] })`;

Which returns the following.

```
[{
  firstname: 'bob',
  manager: '{"firstname":"","surname":""}'
}]
```

I've trawled through [Massive's documentation](https://massivejs.org/docs/options-objects) and not been able to find any reference to using this feature with nested fields.

Is this even possible? Ideally I'd like to craft an options object where i can request any number of fields from the root document but also select any subset of fields from nested objects within that document.

Any information would be greatly appreciated thanks.